# Quais são os meios de conexões que uma aplicação C# pode ter com o SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Eu gostaria de saber quais são os tipos de conexões que uma determinada aplicação desenvolvida em C# pode ter com o banco de dados SQL Server. Entre todas, qual é a mais eficiente?

Answer (score 1):

Em tese pode ter quantas alguém quiser criar. Você pode criar uma, pode comprar de fornecedores terceiros ou conseguir algum projeto de código aberto.

A mais eficiente, até se prove em contrário é a nativa, que faz acesso direto no cliente do SQL Server ([SQLNCLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client-programming?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).

Muitas pessoas usam OLEDB, mas li algo sobre abandonar o suporte a ele, não sei como está. O ADO é um dos mais usados hoje em dia. Também pode usar ODBC, mas eu não faria isto.

Está se tornando cada vez mais comum, ainda que eu ache um exagero, o uso de ORMs, como o Entity Framework, NHibernate e até mesmo o Dapper.

Cada um deles vai adicionando camadas no outro.

Comment: @Leonardo Se você não tem nenhum parâmetro ou requisito e deseja apenas experimentar, dá uma olhada no que é mais popular e tem a comunidade mais forte - digo isso porque não sei se você domina o inglês - em ptBR é um pouco mais difícil achar alguns recursos. Drapper é um "micro-ORM" (e se não me engano, o SO usa ele), se você está querendo "brincar", dê uma olhada nele. EF e NHibernate aparentemente tem uma curva de aprendizado mais acentuada.